# Paint all pixels (excluding transparant) in PNG with Javascript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, webkit, css, paint

I need to create a silhouette of a PNG with Javascript/CSS. Is this possible?

I tried the following:
Stack the PNG with lowered opacity multiple times with absolute positioning and z-index.
This does not work.

Unfortunately I can't use PHP or something else then Javascript and CSS.

I got some ideas with overlays and such but I can't figure out how to do it. Any tips?

update: This only needs to work in webkit browsers, so you can bring your webkit trickbox! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible in plain HTML/CSS.

It would be possible in embedded SVG using a [filter](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feColorMatrix) such as `feColorMatrix` to set all channels to one colour except the opacity.

It would be possible in a `<canvas>` using a [composite operation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-globalcompositeoperation), such as first drawing the image, then drawing a single colour over the top with `source-out` mode.

It might be possible in IE using a [MaskFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533013%28VS.85%29.aspx), using the MaskFilter to generate a masking colour (eg. white) laid over a fixed colour (eg. black). However I think you'll lose any variable-opacity smooth edges.

It's going to be a lot of browser-sniffing and annoyance. I'd try to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try your suggestions. I forgot to mention that it only needs to work in webkit browsers.

Comment: Canvas compositing is great :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering you've tagged this with `webkit`, you should have a look at the [*Surfin' Safari* blog post about CSS masks](http://webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/).

E.g. Is this what you want?

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
div {
    width: 215px;
    height: 174px;
    background: black;
    -webkit-mask-image: url("http://webkit.org/images/icon-gold.png");
}
</style>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Masks are not what I'm searching for. Except for if I can mask every colored pixel excluding transparant ones.